# datetime format changed between mysql 5.0 and 5.1?

Tags: mysql, database, replication, time

I've upgraded a mysql slave from mysql 5.0 to mysql 5.1. during the catch up, the replication failed on a query with incorrect datetime value:

```
110919 13:56:18 [ERROR] Slave SQL: Error 'Incorrect datetime value: '2010-03-14 02:35:34.0' for column 'creation_date' at row 1' on query.
```

I've tried to re-insert the query, and it failed again, then I fixed the value to:

```
2010-03-14 02:35:34
```

and the query accepted.

How can I set mysql to approve such datetime values in order to prevent future problems?

My guess will be that it was set on the table description, and was reset during mysql_upgrade.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mysql 5.1 manipulates microseconds as the same way mysql 5.0 do, however microseconds cannot be stored into a column of any temporal data type. Any microseconds part is discarded as per Mysql Doc: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html. However, since you are getting error with this, you can enable allow invalid dates using the sql mode setting in mysql.

```
sql-mode=allow_invalid_dates
```

in my.cnf or my.ini (depending on your OS).

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_allow_invalid_dates

PS: It is surprising that the date & time you provided in your question is actually a non-existent time in DST (14th March 2010):)

Answer (score 0):

You may have to set the datetime_format in my.cnf

Here is what is very, very unusual. The variables [**date_format**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_date_format) and [**datetime_format**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_datetime_format) are present in MySQL 5.x:

```
mysql> select version();
+----------------------+
| version()            |
+----------------------+
| 5.0.81-community-log |
+----------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> show variables like 'date%format';
+-----------------+-------------------+
| Variable_name   | Value             |
+-----------------+-------------------+
| date_format     | %Y-%m-%d          |
| datetime_format | %Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s |
+-----------------+-------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

If you look them up in the MySQL Documentation, it says they are unused. Yet, to my surprise, you can set them in your session. Here is how:

```
mysql> set date_format = '%Y%m%d';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> show variables like 'date%format';
+-----------------+-------------------+
| Variable_name   | Value             |
+-----------------+-------------------+
| date_format     | %Y%m%d            |
| datetime_format | %Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s |
+-----------------+-------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Question: Can you set it globally ???  (This example is MySQL 5.5.12 in Windows)

```
mysql> set global date_format = '%Y%m%d';
ERROR 1238 (HY000): Variable 'date_format' is a read only variable
```

At least you cannot on the command line. What about in my.cnf (my.ini) ???

I added this to my.ini on my PC

```
[mysqld]
date_format="%Y%m%d"
```

restarted mysql and got this:

```
mysql> select version();
+------------+
| version()  |
+------------+
| 5.5.12-log |
+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> show variables like 'date%format';
+-----------------+-------------------+
| Variable_name   | Value             |
+-----------------+-------------------+
| date_format     | %Y%m%d            |
| datetime_format | %Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s |
+-----------------+-------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Although it is officially undocumented, you can play with the format at your discretion.

Give it a Try !!!

DISCLAIMER : Should any of your datetime data be caught or killed, I will disavow any knowledge of your actions.